# Flattening nested list pattern with sed/perl-like regex or awk

Tags: regex, perl, sed, nested-lists, flatten

I have a simple nested list-type pattern that I'd like to flatten so that each child item is prefixed with its parent item using a regular expression (if it's possible) using sed or command line perl. I appreciate that it's fairly trivial to do this using loops/recursion in a simple perl program, but I'm interested in whether it can be done via regex. If it's not possible to do via regex, then I'll consider alternatives via awk or similar (e.g. trivial perl on command line) that can still be easily used in a Unix pipe.

Notes / Assumptions:

1. For my particular usage, I'm piping input/output as part of a larger data transformation chain that already has several command line perl regexes, hence the preference to be consistent.
2. Performance isn't a particular concern - there will be less than 100 items in the list and items will typically be less than 50 characters.
3. No requirement to handle edge cases like parents with no children, or badly formatted list structures (assume data is correct format).
4. The tokens that delimit parent/child items is unimportant - the example below is using '< ' for parent and '> ' for child, but these could be anything.
5. The separator between parent and child in the output is unimportant - the example below is using '.' just as an example.
6. There is only one level of nesting (assume I can derive how to manage further nesting levels, should I need to).
7. Number of parents and number of children (total and per parent) are unknown.
8. Number of children can differ between parents.

Example input:

```
< Parent1
> Child1
> Child2
< Parent2
> Child3
< Parent3
> Child4
> Child5
> Child6
> Child7
```

Desired output:

```
Parent1.Child1
Parent1.Child2
Parent2.Child3
Parent3.Child4
Parent3.Child5
Parent3.Child6
Parent3.Child7
```

Best attempt:

```
perl -0pe 's/< (.*)\n> (.*)\n/\1.\2\n/g'
```

Best attempt output:

```
Parent1.Child1
> Child2
Parent2.Child3
Parent3.Child4
> Child5
> Child6
> Child7
```

Obviously my best attempt is only handling the initial child of each parent as part of the multi-line match. I know why, I just don't know what technique to allow repeatedly printing the parent capture group for each child capture group printed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `regex` requirement seems a little strange when this problem does not seem to be suited to regex at all.

Comment: Just see how simple it can be `awk '/</{p=$2}/>/{print p"."$2}' file`

Comment: Or if you want to have those characters on the names, you can be more explicit: `awk '$1 == "<" {Foo=$2} $1==">" {print Foo"."$2}' Input.txt`

Comment: Also, if you are piping data using the standard unix pipe `|`, `awk` should be fine also.

Comment: Thanks for the awk suggestion - I'll edit the question to include awk.

Comment: I'm still interested in whether it's possible with regex, though :-)

Comment: In the end, I went with an awk solution very similar to that given by @merlin2011 above, but I don't think it was given as an answer so I can't mark it as correct.

Comment: @Ben, you can always add your own answer and accept that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not bothering with a regex, but using perl

```
perl -lne '$p=$_ if s/< //; print "$p.$_" if s/> //' file.txt
```

Btw, the reason why using a single regex for this problem is silly, is because you're trying to do more than one transformation.  You're wanting to prefix the children with their parent's name.  And you're also wanting to strip the parents.  Those are 2 distinct operations and so trying to dream up a way to combine them doesn't make any sense.

The below uses 3 regexes to accomplish the transformation that you want, but obviously the above is a lot more clear.

```
perl -0777 -pe '
    s/(^<.*\n)((?:>.*\n)*)/$2$1/mg;
    s/^> (?=.*?^< ([^\n]*))/$1./smg;
    s/^<.*\n//mg;
  ' file.txt
```

Comment: You shouldn't need that `"\n"` in the print with `-l`.

Comment: Thanks for the brief perl non-regex suggestion @Miller - I'm still interested in the possibility of regex solution, but will certainly try yours out (tomorrow)

Comment: These solutions also both worked, so I've opted to mark this as correct, despite going with an awk solution - thanks @Miller

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed '/</{h;ba};G;s/[><] //g;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\.\1/p;:a;d' file
```

#### Explanation

- this is a `if-then-else-fi` by sed.
- `/</` similar as option in `if`
- `{h;ba};` similar as commands after `then`
- `G;s/[><] //g;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\.\1/p;` similar as commands after `else`
- `:a;d` similar as `fi`

Using awk

```
awk '/^</{s=$2;next}{$0=s"."$2}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;/^(< (Parent.*))\n> (Child.*)/{s//\2.\3\n\1/;P};D' file
```

This pairs `Parents` with `Child` until two `Parents` occur then it discards the first `Parent`.

N.B. the `Parent`,`Child` regexp is superfluous:

```
sed -r '$!N;/^(< (.*))\n> (.*)/{s//\2.\3\n\1/;P};D' file
```

would work also.